# How to design a neural network to recognize distinct features?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, shapes

I am trying to build a neural network in tensorflow, using tf.layers.dense interface. I want to figure out how can I make tensorflow see all the features as sets of features.

An example:

Classifying a group of people as a good/bad basketball team (0- bad, 1- good).
Each person has his/her own features (gender, age, height, weight, years playing basketball). To classify the whole team as good or bad, the neural network would have to see features of 5 people and the output should be either 0 or 1.

Now in this example, how do I make the network see all the different features associated with different people and output a single classification digit?

I assume it has something to do with the shapes of the input tensors, I tried making the tensor of the shape [batch_size, number_of_players, number_of_features] which would look like this:

```
[
 [[gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball],
  [gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball],
  [gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball], //team1
  [gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball],
  [gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball]],

 [[gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball],
  [gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball],
  [gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball], //team2
  [gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball],
  [gender, age, height, weight, years_playing_basketball]]
]
```

Naturally, after passing this tensor through several tf.layers.dense layers, the output would also be a 3D tensor while I would only need a single number as an output. On the other hand, If I put all team features into a single array, I believe the network wouldn't have any way of knowing that these are in fact features of 5 different people. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Hopefully, your network would learn to the input correctly and correctly identify weights. You could speed this process up by using a hidden layer size of 5, perhaps inducing the network to use each node in the layer as the overall rating for each individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Naturally, after passing this tensor through several tf.layers.dense layers, the output would also be a 3D tensor while I would only need a single number as an output.

You would need a 1D tensor with `batch_size` different outputs, correct? One output per full team in the batch.

> On the other hand, If I put all team features into a single array, I believe the network wouldn't have any way of knowing that these are in fact features of 5 different people.

This is the most common solution, and probably also the best. Definitely the easiest. This solution only works if you are sure that every team always has 5 people, I suppose that is a safe assumption?

This solution is often going to be referred to as "flattening" (in many frameworks you can convert a `(number_of_players, number_of_features)` tensor into a `(number_of_players * number_of_features)` tensor using a function called `flatten`). Yes, you're correct that the neural network has no way of ''knowing'' that the age feature of team member X is somehow similarly important as the age feature of team member Y, or ''knowing'' that the age and gender features of team member X are somehow more closely related to each other than the age feature of team member X and the gender feature of team member Y... but that's generally fine. If it turns out to be important to learn something like that, it can still do so.

---

One additional tip: if the order in which different persons appear in the same team does not matter (e.g. if there is not some important, consistent position-based ordering or something like that), I'd recommend **augmenting your data** by also including shuffled versions of the teams you already have to your data. For example, if you data contains a team [P1, P2, P3, P4, P5] (where every P is a sequence of features corresponding to one person), I'd augment the dataset by also adding a team [P2, P1, P3, P4, P5], and a team [P3, P1, P2, P4, P5], etc. You can basically add all possible permutations.

Comment: Yes, I actually meant one output per batch :) thank you for the detailed answer!